# Corsair Voyager Air 2 not showing up when on battery power + USB 3.0 connector

Tags: hard-drive

I am currently using a Raspberry Pi2, and a corsair voyager air 2.

The Corsair device is a 1TB HD connected via USB3.0 cable, and comes with it's own battery power.

Plugging in the device, turning it off/on, switching USB ports.. nothing shows up.  Could it be that I cannot run the Voyager Air 2 off battery when utilizing USB?? only with it's wifi connector?  that sounds like a flaw.

all I see is my Wifi dongle,

`$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 7392:7811 Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]`

Comment: You could have a look at `dmesg | tail` output before and after you plug it in to see if anything is indicated there.

Answer (score 1):

The Voyager 2 must be turned on. Press the power switch until the battery light blinks. You should see "... ID 1b1c:1a08 Corsair" with lsusb. Also, the power light should be blue.